# Microsoft Graph API - Copying SharePoint file - Item not found

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm working with Graph API against Microsoft Teams team's SharePoint site.

I'm following the example on this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/long-running-actions-overview?tabs=http) and have an issue. I'm able to query the location provided by the copy endpoint and get a "Completed" status that also provides a ResourceId. But I'm unable to use this resource id in any queries and only getting "Item not found".
Example of paths tried:
/drives/{driveId}/items/{resource-id-returned-from-monitor-url}
/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{resource-id-returned-from-monitor-url}

The {driveID} is the driveId specified in the parentReference.DriveId in the copy file body.

I'm using the v1 Graph endpoint to get the file.

Btw, I can see the file fine in the correct folder within SharePoint.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Oskar

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't using the DriveId supplied by the /education/***/setUpResourcesFolder Location header but rather the Drive of the class.
Fixed by using the driveId part of the Location URL.